# Knockout mapping regarding select lists

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-mapping-plugin

I am completely stumped.  I think this should be an easy task yet it completely evades me.  I am trying to just create a select list but for some reason this isn't binding.  I get no errors in the Console.

Here is my Javascript

```
var data = {
    "StoreList": [{
    "StoreNo": "02",
    "StoreName": "Store02"
  }, {
    "StoreNo": "03",
    "StoreName": "Store03"
  }, {
    "StoreNo": "14",
    "StoreName": "Store14"
  }, {
    "StoreNo": "15",
    "StoreName": "Store15"
  }]
};

var viewModel = {};
viewModel = ko.mapping.fromJS(data);
ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

Here is my HTML

```
<select height="20" data-bind="options: viewModel.StoreList, optionsText: 'StoreName'"></select>
```

My fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/S7cqp/3/

Comment: -1 For not making any effort with a descriptive title.

Comment: Worst. Question. Title. EVER.   `jkfkjkskfjskfjskfjskjfsk`... seriously?

Comment: I like it! Certainly caught my eye.

Comment: @AndFinally - don't encourage it. Or you will get `adfasdfasdfasdfa` titles all over.

Comment: I apologize for the title...SO wouldn't let me save it with the original title...so I had to put gobley gook in there to get it submitted.  Apparently any question with the word Knockout has already been answered.  Seems like a flaw in their submission code.

Comment: SO doesn't let you do that when there is an exact other question with that title. Means that there is a good chance it is a duplicate and already has an answer (did you check???).

Comment: @Oded I guess you're right..

Comment: There wasn't an exact post with my original title. I changed the title like 10 times and no matter what it found something similar though none of the contents of the SO posts were remotely related.  @Oded are you just going to troll me or help

Comment: I am not trolling, just trying to keep Stack Overflow clean. You got my attention with that title you posted. I am not a knockout guy, or I would try to answer.

Comment: I immediately changed the title after I posted, thinking correctly that once the post was in their system I could change the title to what I really wanted and thereby get around whatever title checking code they have implemented, which is quite poor if you ask me.  I didn't think someone would try to answer it 1 minute after it was posted.

Comment: In chrome console I see the following errors: Uncaught `Error: Unable to parse bindings.
Message: ReferenceError: viewModel is not defined;
Bindings value: options: viewModel.StoreList, optionsText: 'StoreName' `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't put `viewModel` into the data-bind attribute. It is just a name of the variable where your VM is stored. Your binding should look as follow:

```
<select height="20" data-bind="options: StoreList, optionsText: 'StoreName'"></select>
```

Here is a working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/vyshniakov/S7cqp/8/

Comment: brilliant...I knew it was something dumb.